# import statement not working but require working in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, es6-modules

In my application created with create-react-app

*helper.js*

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'

//function definitions
//Func1

module.exports = {
  //functions
  //Func1
};
```

*Components.js*

```
import { Func1 } from './helper'
```

Failed to compile
'./helper' does not contain an export named 'Func1'.

But compiles finely when i use

```
var cloneDeep = require('lodash/cloneDeep');
```

instead of

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'
```

in my helper.js

What is the problem with using *import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'* 
I am trying to use es 6 imports for consistency

Comment: Do you export from `helper` ?

Comment: Yes.  module.exports = { FuncName1, Funcname2 } from helper

Comment: You should add more detail in source code, and detail error too

Comment: May not be related but why do you export your helpers with `module.exports` and not `export .. ` syntax?

Comment: @bamse  . What difference can module.exports instead of export make.

Comment: lodash help at https://lodash.com/ says only to use var at = require('lodash/at')  and not import statements . Maybe can't use import with lodash.